# Counting Number of Rows containing each string in a different column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem:
I have a table called FOOD with a column "NAME" containing name of foods, such as "Rice", "White Rice" , "Milk", "Soy Milk" etc.

I need to filter out the rows which have a NAME containing only a single word, and then count in how many rows each of these single words appears in the NAME column as a part of a name of a food.

For example if the NAME column is: "Rice", "White Rice" , "Milk", "Soy Milk", "Brown Rice", Then the result should be Rice - count is 3 and Milk - count is 2.

I know how to get the values in NAME column which contain a single word:

```
SELECT NAME AS lones FROM FOOD WHERE NAME NOT LIKE '% %' GROUP BY lones
```

How do I continue from here?

Thanks

Comment: You want to "filter out the rows which have a NAME containing only a single word" but then how would the count of "Rice" be 3? Wouldn't it become 2?

Comment: The "filter out the rows which have a NAME containing only a single word"  is only the first step. After that, for each one of these single words, I need to count how many times it appeared in the NAME column as a part of a name of a food. So the count of "Rice" would be 3, because it appeared in "Rice", "Brown Rice" and "White Rice"

Comment: so are you just looking for a count for how many times that name appears?

Comment: Yes, for each name that is a single word, and in "appears" I mean as a part of a name. So "Rice" appears in "Rice", "White Rice" etc

Comment: Selective aggregates might be what you are looking for: http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. I JOIN `food` against a temp table consisting of single-word foods (which I create by selecting names without space in them).

The JOIN condition is that the single-word food is present in the joined food table's name column.

POSITION() works like indexOf() function in other languages. It returns 0 if the search string is not found in the source string.

```
select single_word_foods.name, count(*) 
from food INNER JOIN 
(select distinct name from food where position(' ' in name) = 0) as single_word_foods
on POSITION(single_word_foods.name in food.name) > 0
group by single_word_foods.name;
```

Comment: This solution seems to return count values which aren't possible. In the FOOD table I have around 180k rows but for some values in the solution table (in which, the first column is a single word that is a food name and the second is count), the count is larger than 180k. Could it be because of the group by in the end (group by single_word_foods.name)? Does this group_by sum the results for the group? (I should state that some single words foods can appear twice in the NAME column of FOOD table. For example, the NAME column could be: "Rice","Milk","Rice","White Milk","Brown Rice")

Comment: @AtsrA I made it use distinct single word names. Can you check now?

Comment: The results seems to make sense now. Thanks a lot!